# Is it possible to reload only a view inside a state in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, reload

my problem is that I have two different views inside a AngularJS state, as seen beneath:

```
$stateProvider.state('root.base.persons', {
    url : 'persons/:id',
    views : {
        'level-1@root' : {
            templateUrl : 'html/person-level-1.html',
            controller : 'PersonLevel1Controller',
            controllerAs : 'personLevel1Ctrl'
        },
        'level-1-tabs@root' : {
            templateUrl : 'html/person-tabs.html',
            controller : 'PersonTabsController',
            controllerAs : 'personTabsCtrl'
        }
    },
```

Let's say the first view of the code above is a header in a webpage, and beneath it I have different views being loaded. I'm having a hard time discovering how can I refresh the content of the header when a refresh button that is placed in the header is clicked, without triggering the same reload in the "child" views/states beneath this parent state. I've tried `$state.reload`, `$state.go` and `$state.transitionTo` but I can't seem to find the answer to it.

Basically, is it possible in Angular to reload **only** a view inside a state?

Appreciate your time and answers.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

#### Use:

```
var options = { reload: true };
$state.go(to, params, options);
```

> ### $state.go options
>
> **reload** (v0.2.5) - `{boolean=false|string|object}`, If `true` will force transition even if no state or params have changed. It will reload the resolves and views of the current state and parent states. If `reload` is a string (or state object), the state object is fetched (by name, or object reference); and \ the transition reloads the resolves and views for that matched state, and all its children states.
>
> [— UI-Router API Reference - $state.go options](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.4.2/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go)